# If $X, Y$ are two iid random variables is it true that $E[f(X) 1\{X \geq Y\}] \geq (1/2) E[f(X)]$?

Tags: inequality, random-variables

Suppose that $f$ is some nonnegative function. If $X, Y$ are two independent and identically distributed random variables, is it true that
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X) 1\{X \geq Y\}] \geq \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[f(X)] 
$$

Intuitively, this seems to be true: since $X$ and $Y$ are independent copies, $X \geq Y$ and $Y \geq X$ are equally likely events. So can we symmetrize? For instance: I believe we have
$$
\mathbb{E}_{X, Y}[f(X) 1\{X \geq Y\}] = 
\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon, X, Y}[f(X) 1\{\epsilon(X-Y) \geq 0\}]
\geq \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[f(X)]. 
$$
Above $\epsilon$ is equally likely to be $+1, -1$ independently of $X, Y$. If the first equality holds, then the second one is clearly correct (just by integrating over $\epsilon$ first). To justify the first equality, my reasoning is that $X-Y$ is a symmetric random variable, so it should have the same distribution as $\epsilon(X- Y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $X$ be the number of heads after $4$ flips of a fair coin, and $Y$ the number of heads after $4$ flips of a different fair coin. Then let $f$ be a function on $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ be as follows: $f(0)=32$, $f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4) = 0$. So

- $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ is $32$ times the probability that all coin flips of the 1st coin comes up tails, and
- $\mathbb{E}[f(X)|1_{X \ge Y}]$ turns out to be $32$ times the probability that all coin flips of {\em both} coins come up tails.

Then $$\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = 2^{-4}\times 32 = 2.$$

However, $$\mathbb{E}[f(x) \times 1_{X \ge Y}] = 2^{-4}\times 2^{-4} \times 32$$ $$= 2^{-4}\times \mathbb{E}[f(X)].$$